# How can I retrieve the entire old ethereum blockchain data for data processing

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I want to get the "entire" ethereum blockchain data, not just from a few sets of smart contracts. By data I mean, transaction details including the generated logs.

I can get real-time data using Infura, but it's pretty much impossible to fetch all the old data, it would simply cost too much because I would simply have to do too many network requests.

I need the old data because I am trying to make an indexed database out of the "append-only" ethereum transaction data so that I can easily query it.

To be more precise, I would like to retrieve all NFT(ERC721, ERC1155) transfer transactions and their logs. So that I can do the following queries and much more: all the NFT owned by a particular wallet, transfer histories of a particular NFT token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions I have discovered.

1. Just like @Mikko has mentioned, you can run your own node. And it seemed not be as complex as I have expected. You can search for "geth" and then simply connect this node to your web3 library, just like connecting to Infura.

But I have not tried this and found a much better solution.

2. Google cloud Bigquery's public data set has all the old ethereum data. Bigquery is Google's data warehouse service, where you can use simple SQL to query your data.  It adds new data every day. I have already tested some simple queries from its console and the result was good.

I am planning to fetch all the old data I need from bigquery and store it in my own database and afterwards get real time data from infura. Now that I dont have to fetch all the old data from infura, the price becomes very affordable.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by

- [Run your own node](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1370323189486784513)
- Query data from your node - locally it is fast
- For some data, you might need to run the node [in archival mode](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/99124/620)

You can use the same Web3 / JSON-RPC APIs on a local node than you are using on Infura.

Answer (score 2):

you may check this https://github.com/blockchain-etl/ethereum-etl
It is a Python library for ETL (extract, transform and load) jobs for Ethereum blocks, transactions, ERC20 / ERC721 tokens, transfers, receipts, logs, contracts, and internal transactions.

For example, you may run the cli command

```
> ethereumetl export_token_transfers --start-block 0 --end-block 500000 \
--provider-uri file://$HOME/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc --output token_transfers.csv
```

You may export ERC20 and ERC721 transfers by specific the block number which enable you to query the old data.

Data is also available in Google BigQuery.